# Limitation of Wiener filter in image denoising

Tags: image-processing, denoising

In image processing, up to which value of mean and variance can a Wiener filter be used to denoise the image?

Wiener filtering can be used when variance of the noisy image is low, but I don't know the specific values of variance and mean.

What are limitations of the Wiener filter?

Comment: Why do you think it can't be used after a certain value? The Wiener filter minimizes the mean square error, regardless of the noise level. Whether there is a point at which the noise degradation makes linear filtering a poor choice for processing (in terms of image quality improvement) is another question.

Answer (score -1):

For image denoising the wiener filter is very limited hence it won't be able to deal with actual noise.
It can't take advantage of the spatial information in the image, only maximize the SNR within the frequency buckets.

Comment: Of course the Wiener filter takes advantage of spatial information. It’s a linear filter, a convolution. A non-linear filter might be more effective for noise reduction, but this argument makes no sense.